# Retrieve value of single column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using the controller bellow i am able to get all database of Users table but if i want to get only users "Email" column, how should I write this controller?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = db.Users.Where(d => d.Subscriptions.Any(x => x.Status == true));
    return View(users.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `.Select` only the column you need:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = db.Users
        .Where(d => d.Subscriptions.Any(x => x.Status == true))
        .Select(u => u.Email);

    return View(users);
}
```

Note that in this case you are returning an `IEnumerable<string>` (I suppose `Email` property is string)

If you want to return something more complex, you should create a new object with just the properties you need, like:

```
public class UserWithEmail
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = db.Users
        .Where(d => d.Subscriptions.Any(x => x.Status == true))
        .Select(u => new UserWithEmail() { UserId = u.UserId, Email = u.Email };

    return View(users);
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks, a quick question do you know how to return view directly without passing to view? i want to print the value of variables or array test purpose that's why.

Comment: I didn't understand you question, I suggest you to ask a new question for this :-)